# What would the presence of a hub metabolite in a metabolic pathway signify?

Tags: metabolism, fat-metabolism, pathway, cycle

Say I have a metabolic pathway, consisting of multiple metabolites and reactions. On analyzing the pathway I find that among all the metabolite, one metabolite is the hub metabolite (hub metabolite is the metabolite such that maximum number of reactions involve that particular metabolite). 
What is the significance of this metabolite or of this pathway?

Comment: It's hard to say without knowing what metabolite you're talking about -- all metabolites have different roles, and you won't learn much about it simply from network degrees. You have probably hit upon either a common cofactor like NAD or ATP, a small ion like H+, or a common group donor like glutamate.

Comment: @Roland isn't there any generalized perspective of it?

Comment: Not much, really ...  The "hub" metabolites of course give rise to many products, and they tend to be present in high concentrations (but not all are). But beyond that, you really need to look into the biochemistry. The examples I mentioned have completely different functions.

Comment: By your own definition you are talking about several pathways not just one. All you can say about the metabolite is that it's an important intermediate. What else would you imagine?

Comment: @David I am trying to figure out what else can be inferred from the hub metabolite... hence posted the question :)

Comment: Forgive me if I am wrong, but you sound like a computing science student who has been asked to perform some mathematical analysis on metabolism and is now wondering what the results mean and whether they are of any interest to biologists. I say this partly through experience and partly because I'd never heard the term 'metabolic hub', but on Googling find a [paper](http://journals.plos.org/plosbiology/article?id=10.1371%2Fjournal.pbio.0030228) from a computing science department using it. Note that paper refers to a metbolic network — as I said, several pathways.

Comment: @David you are absolutely correct. I am a computer science student. I have not been asked to do anything, but I am doing it on my own. And thanks a lot for the resource. Hope I will be able to get more insights regarding metabolic pathways :)

Comment: @Rishika — You were right to post, but try to make personal contact with biochemists. You need to find out whether there are real problems that your skills can solve. I know from experience that it can be difficult, and computing scientists have come up with things that are actually no use in the real world. In this case I would think you would just come up with things like ATP, NAD, glucose 6-phosphate, glutamate, the importance of which is already known. However if you can find a real problem, then your work can be worthwhile. Good luck.

Comment: @David would you mind if I could contact you somehow?

Comment: @Rishika — If you wish. You should be able to work out an email address from my profile.